# Monkey-patching Jasmine's it() function to log errors

Tags: error-handling, logging, promise, typescript, jasmine

The introduction of async native support in Jasmine doesn't log the errors (i.e., specific line number where the error occurs) to the console. So, to get around this behavior and to make the errors appears in the console, I came up with this following solution to patch Jasmine.

I have the following function which I implemented to monkey patch the Jasmine. And I would like to reuse the same function for other functions like `beforeEach`, `beforeAll` and so on..

```
     function patchJasmineForAsyncError(method: string) {
        let oldFn = window[method];
        if (method === 'it' || method === 'fit') {
            window[method] = function (desc: string, fn: Function) {
                    oldFn(description, (done) => {
                    let p = fn();
                    if (p instanceof Promise) {
                        p.then(() => done()).catch(e => {
                            console.error(e);
                            done.fail(e);
                        });
                    }
                    });
            }
        } else {
            window[method] = function (axn: Function) {
                oldFn((done) => {
                    let p = axn();
                    if (p instanceof Promise) {
                        p.then(() => done()).catch(e => {
                            console.error(e);
                            done.fail(e);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see the second part of the function (the `else` block) has quite a lot of duplication. I was wondering if there is an elegant way to minimize this and implement the function.

Note: the `it` and `fit` functions have two arguments `desc` and `fn`.. but the `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`.. etc have only one argument `axn`.

Comment: `description` or `desc`?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru I [didn't approve your edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92845) because that is something that can be reviewed (and you should mention that in your answer!), and hopefully everybody knows this, but in case not:  now that answers have been submitted, [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just factor it out into a closure

```
function patchJasmineForAsyncError(method: string) {
    let oldFn = window[method];
    function create_logger(fn: Function) {
        return (done) => {
            let p = fn();
            if (p instanceof Promise) {
                p.then(done).catch(e => {
                    console.error(e);
                    done.fail(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (method === 'it' || method === 'fit') {
        window[method] = function(desc: string, fn: Function) {
            oldFn(desc, create_logger(fn));
        }
    } else {
        window[method] = function (axn: Function) {
            oldFn(create_logger(axn));
        }
    }
}
```

We can clean this up a bit more by getting rid of some magic. I also got rid of the `() => done()` because that's the same as `done`.

```
function patchJasmineForAsyncError(method: string) {
    let oldFn = window[method];
    function create_logger(fn: Function) {
        return (done) => {
            let p = fn();
            if (p instanceof Promise) {
                p.then(done).catch(e => {
                    console.error(e);
                    done.fail(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    let allowed_methods = ['it', 'fit'];
    if (allowed_methods.includes(method)) {
        window[method] = function(desc: string, fn: Function) {
            oldFn(desc, create_logger(fn));
        }
    } else {
        window[method] = function (axn: Function) {
            oldFn(create_logger(axn));
        }
    }
}
```

We can also reduce some of the duplication in assigning to `window[method]` if we're okay with adding a slight slow-down to the function, which should be fine.

```
function patchJasmineForAsyncError(method: string) {
    let oldFn = window[method];
    function create_logger(fn: Function) {
        return (done) => {
            let p = fn();
            if (p instanceof Promise) {
                p.then(done)
                 .catch(e => {
                    console.error(e);
                    done.fail(e);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    let allowed_methods = ['it', 'fit'];
    window[method] = function() {
        if (allowed_methods.includes(method)) {
            oldFn(arguments[0], create_logger(arguments[1]));
        } else {
            oldFn(create_logger(arguments[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damnn. Seems like I am too late to post my answer :P I did the way you did in the first method. Thanks a lot for the amazing answer :)